# How to perform count by value operation on spark's Dataset without grouping values?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a table represented by spark Dataset< Row >

```
origin.show();

+------+
|Origin|
+------+
|   USA|
| Japan|
|   USA|
|   USA|
| Japan|
|Europe|
+------+
```

I want to build additional "countByValue" column to get table like

```
+------+-----+
|Origin|Count|
+------+-----+
|Europe|    1|
|   USA|    3|
|   USA|    3|
|   USA|    3|
| Japan|    2|
| Japan|    2|
+------+-----+
```

I found solution but it seems very inefficient. I group origin dataset and use count function.

```
Dataset<Row> grouped = origin.groupBy(originCol).agg(functions.count(originCol));
grouped.show();

+------+-----+
|Origin|Count|
+------+-----+
|Europe|    1|
|   USA|    3|
| Japan|    2|
+------+-----+
```

Then I just join result table with origin dataset.

```
Dataset<Row> finalDs = origin.join(grouped, originCol);
```

**Is there any other more efficiant way to perform such operation?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write query with Window:

```
origin.withColumn("cnt", count('Origin).over(Window.partitionBy('Origin)))
```

Remember to import `org.apache.spark.sql.functions._` and  `org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window`

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to do

```
org.apache.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
    ("USA"),
    ("Japan"),
    ("USA"),
    ("USA"),
    ("Japan"),
    ("Europe")
).toDF("origin")


val result = df.groupBy("origin").agg(collect_list($"origin").alias("origin1"),
  count("origin").alias("count"))
  .withColumn("origin", explode($"origin1")).drop("origin")
```